# Spawning functions without exporting them

Tags: erlang, export, spawn

I am new to erlang and have a bit of a headache with the following scenario:

Take this code:

```
-module (so).
-export ( [foo/0] ).

bar () ->
    receive 
        die -> ok;
        Msg -> io:format ("I say ~p.~n", [Msg] )
    end.


bar (Name) ->
    receive 
        die -> ok;
        Msg -> io:format ("~s says ~p.~n", [Name, Msg] )
    end.

foo () ->
    Bar = spawn (fun bar/0),
    Bar ! "Hello",
    Bar ! die,
    Baz = spawn (?MODULE, bar, ["Alice"] ), % bar/1 not exported
    Baz ! "Hello",
    Baz ! die.
```

The process spawned with `spawn/1` works fine, but the second process spawned with `spawn/3` fails as expected because I haven't exported `bar/1` and hence I get `{undef,[{so,bar,["Alice"]}]}`. Both spawn functions that take a parameter list (`spawn/3` and `spawn/4`) also take a module name. But I don't want to export `bar/1`, because it is only used internally and never needs to be invoked from outside the module.

**How can I spawn a function with arguments without exporting it?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can just put the call inside another `fun` like this:

```
spawn(fun() -> bar("alice") end)
```